# awk: why can't awk produces complete list of progressive float numbers?

Tags: linux, awk

```
    kitty@mypad:~$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0.01;i<=0.1;i=i+0.01) print i}'
    0.01
    0.02
    0.03
    0.04
    0.05
    0.06
    0.07
    0.08
    0.09
    0.1
    kitty@mypad:~$ awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0.01;i<=0.2;i=i+0.01) print i}'
    0.01
    0.02
    0.03
    0.04
    0.05
    0.06
    0.07
    0.08
    0.09
    0.1
    0.11
    0.12
    0.13
    0.14
    0.15
    0.16
    0.17
    0.18
    0.19
```

you see, for i<=k, when k is 0.1, it produces as expected, but when k is 0.2, or 0.3, blabla, the last number (0.2 or 0.3) is not produces

why?

Answer (score 7):

Floating point imprecision. Neither 0.1 nor 0.2 nor 0.3 can be represented exactly  by a finite binary float -- only fractions with powers of two in the denominator can (up to a point) -- so awk is doing its calculations with approximate values. Sometimes these will be a little larger than what you expect, sometimes a little smaller. When they are a little larger, the test `i <= 0.2` is false an iteration earlier than it would otherwise be.

The usual way to deal with this is to use a small epsilon to offset it, i.e.

```
#                             v-- here
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=0.01;i<=0.2+1e-9;i=i+0.01) print i}'
```

Note that the epsilon value should be so chosen that it is small enough to not fudge the results but large enough to offset the floating point rounding error. In this case, that means that it should be much smaller than `0.01` and, assuming ieee-754 doubles, not smaller than, say, `0.2 * 1e-12`.

The reason for the latter is that because of the finite mantissa of a floating point, at some point adding a very small epsilon to a number does not change its value even though the epsilon is not zero. For example, I get

```
$ echo | awk '{ print 0.2 + 1e-30 == 0.2 }'
1
```

The estimation of a good epsilon value is not trivial and highly dependent on the calculation in question, so it is difficult to give a general answer to the follow-up question.

Keeping in mind that this pound of salt has to be taken with such recommendations: for simple comparisons of the results of simple calculations like this, you'll want to take no less than something on the order of, say, `value * 1e-12` for calculations with double-precision floats (which is what you'll usually have) or `value * 1e-5` for single-precision floats. This is because the mantissa of a double-precision float in ieee-754 (which everyone uses) is 53 binary digits long, which correlates roughly to 16 decimal ones, whereas the single-precision float has 24 binary/7 decimal. You want to stay safely away from that margin by two or three orders of magnitude.

For complex calculations, I have no general advice. Sometimes rounding errors accumulate, so a larger epsilon may be required to offset them. In some calculations -- for example numeric differentiation through a difference quotient -- what the best epsilon value would be depends on values you do not know before calculating the quotient, since you have to consider the effects of catastrophic cancellation when subtracting two floating point numbers in the numerator against the mathematical implications of a large secant step. In such cases, you need an understanding of both floating points and the problem you're working on.

To get an understanding of the way floating points work and what to expect of them, [this](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html) is as good a place to start as any.

Comment: Alternatively, `awk 'BEGIN { for ( i=1; i<=20; i+=1 ) print i / 10.0 }'` - use integers, which are precise, and only convert to floating-point for the display...